# Remove broken PPA package with unknown option

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, latex

I made the mistake of installing texlive-2016 from a [PPA]{https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016}. I had the default texlive installation for 14.04 installed and tried to install texlive 2016 in its place. The install failed, at which point I tried frantically to remove texlive-2016. I am unable to remove `context` from the newer distribution.

```
dmortens@syllable:~$ sudo dpkg -P context
(Reading database ... 648524 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing context (2016.05.17.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0) ...
unknown option: format
dpkg: error processing package context (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 context
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get remove context`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq context`, and a number of other suggestions. I'm not sure what to make of the `unknown option: format` message. How do I force the removal of this package? It is preventing me from adding or removing any other packages.

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/a/310/15003 helps.

Comment: Use `ppa-purge`  instead of `apt-add-repository --remove`

Comment: @edwinksl and @Anwar, I seem to be unable to install `ppa-purge` because of my broken installation. I believe what I really need to be able to do is remove context and potentially other broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like postrm script of the package is broken. A workaround that helped me is to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/context.postrm`, namely replace

```
case "$1" in
    remove|disappear)
        dhit_call_update_texmf_config format
```

with

```
case "$1" in
    remove|disappear)
        dhit_call_update_texmf_config
```

Then you'll be able to fix your system with `apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the procedure provided by TUG's page?

> If you're re-installing after a previous attempt, be sure to completely remove your failed installation. By default, this would be in these two directories (on Unix-like systems):

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2016
$ rm -rf ~/.texlive2016
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

---

Also, you'd like to remove the PPA. Instructions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed#310).

Comment: Thanks, Filippo. I did follow those instructions for removing the PPA, previously, to no avail. At your suggestion, I also removed an existing texlive installed according to the TUG instructions, also to no effect.