# Package system broken after failed attempt at updating to TeX-Live2016 (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, texlive

I tried to update texlive from 2013 version to 2016 version (through adding the ppa ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016. This failed, and I tried to revert the changes (purging texlive, to begin all over), and am now stuck. Trying to install/remove/update anything results in unmet dependencies messages, and it tries to remove the package context, but fails. Running apt-get -f install yields the following:

```
Removing context (2016.05.17.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0) ...
unknown option: format
dpkg: error processing package context (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 context
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried using --force-yes remove and tried forcing a purge with dpkg without any luck.

Edit (in response to "marked as duplicate": It might be related to [Remove broken PPA package with unknown option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816314/remove-broken-ppa-package-with-unknown-option), as it's about the context package and actually mentions fiddling with the postrm script. It is not the same as [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa). None of the answers provided any solution. The solution I found might be added to that topic, though.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you check [this previously answered question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) ?

Comment: I've looked at that post, yes, and it did **not** contain any solution to my problem. It is related, sure, but does not provide a fix. My issue, and the solution to it, might be added to that topic, though.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue by removing the context.postrm file (which I located by)

```
sudo updatadb
locate context.post
```

I don't know precisely what is done/not done by this postremoval script, but removing it seemed to resolve the issue. If anyone can clarify/enlighten me on this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Interesting, how did you come up to this solution? Dis you read it somewhere? Id like to check it out

Comment: I came up with it because I saw somewhere among the many discussions I looked through mentioning fiddling with .postinst scripts. I must sadly admit that I can't recall (and can't find) the actual post(s) that mentioned it. It seems that the answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/816314/remove-broken-ppa-package-with-unknown-option is related, and might have solved my issue, though I didn't come across it until now.