# Why Ubuntu stopped publishing signed linux kernel images since 4.16.4?

Tags: kernel

Looking at this [kernel-ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), I noticed that the kernel images for `amd64` since `4.16.4` are all **unsigned**.

Is there a reason why Ubuntu stopped publishing signed kernel images?

Comment: Can't confirm but thought someone said you have to pay Microsoft $100 for signing and it involves a lot of work.

Comment: This post might be of interest to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036216/why-are-linux-kernel-images-missing-from-the-ubuntu-kernel-ppa-for-4-17-rcx-ub#1036216

Comment: I don't think they published signed kernel images on every release. A Kernel maintainer commented on my thread linked above. There used to be a linux-signed-image package separate from linux-image.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think mainline kernel images have been signed previously either. Latest releases just changed the package names.

To verify I checked images against Canonical certificate: https://github.com/slytomcat/UEFI-Boot/blob/master/keys/canonical-uefi-ca.crt

```
❯ sudo sbverify --cert canonical-uefi-ca.crt /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.1-041601-generic
warning: file-aligned section .text extends beyond end of file
warning: checksum areas are greater than image size. Invalid section table?
No signature table present
Unable to read signature data from /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.1-041601-generic
Signature verification failed

❯ sudo sbverify --cert canonical-uefi-ca.crt /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic
Signature verification OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes! all the recent Ubuntu maintenance kernels after K4.16.3> are all unsigned,  the frustration I have is that there is NO Explanation given for this!.

Heads Up NOTE: **Do NOT even try to install these current "unsigned linux-images**" not recommended as doing so trashed my system, my system borked when attempting to install said kernel.

IMO wait until the next major kernel release which is K4.17 when I am hoping the linux-images will contain the required signatures.

**Also no notes or explanation for users who don’t have, or use UEFI secure boot based systems i.e. old fashioned Bios. I still have no idea why these kernels don’t work or install. I have read that these signatures are designed to prevent malware invasions. Just would be helpful to have some documentation.

Comment: To fix broken 4.16.3 see this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030043/unable-to-upgrade-kernel-after-4-16-3/1030377#1030377

Comment: That's interesting? Did you also install modules? I've been pulling mainline form 4.16-rc series and the 4.17-rc series and have had no issues with installation or stability.

Comment: I can also install the unsigned modules, but unfortunately for some reason my system wasn't very stable with it so reverted back to 4.16.3. Would like to figure out why this happened though. Even the 4.17 rc series are unsigned.